# Excel VBA: copy multiple variable sized tables/ranges into large data sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a happy reader of this forum, helped me with a lot of questions but right now there is something i cannot find -yet-. First of all, I'm learning vba, but still a beginner!

Question:

I'm looking for a marco which, when run: Selects a variable range on multiple sheets with variable rows:

So it should Select A25:L25 and than down until the last row where a filled cell is found in the table.I think something like:

```
Range("A25:L25").Select  
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select.)
```

Then it should copy the values, and paste it onto the datasheet "PIVOTDATA", below each other.

The are multiple sheets, of which the number varies. But the range  of the sheets to work through are between 2 sheets: 'Clients' & 'END'

I tried to be as specific as possible, hopefully somebody can help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). Please note that this is not a "develop my code for me" site. But rather a site where you post a snippet of code which is not working. Try and use the Macro recorder to record the code which you require and then paste it with your question and then look at where it is not working. This way you will avoid the Downvotes on your question. What you are asking is rather simple and accomplish-able.

Comment: Have you started an attempt at any of the points in your question? If not you can learn a lot by recording what you want to do in a macro and then going from there. People here are happy to help but won't do it all for you! On that note here are some places to start: If A25:L25 is always the start of the table then consider something like: 'Dim LRow As Long' and then have 'LRow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlup).Row'. Then your table will be in A25:L(LRow). That should help with your variable range issue, try adding it into a recorded macro :) good luck

Comment: @bart1701 seeing as its your first post, i have answered your question. Let me know if its what you needed

Comment: thanks both of you, clear comments on putting more visibility on the effort done before coming here and 'beg for a code'

thanks

Comment: Remember to upvote the answers you choose aswell when you have enough rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 Sub CopyDataToPIVOTDATASheet()

      Dim PivotDataSheet As Worksheet
      Set PivotDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PIVOTDATA")

      Dim CurrentWorkSheetIndex As Long
      Dim CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet
      Dim CurrentWorkSheetLastRow As Long
      Dim PivotDataWorkSheetLastRow As Long

      For CurrentWorkSheetIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clients").Index +1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("END").Index - 1

           Set CurrentWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CurrentWorkSheetIndex)
           CurrentWorkSheet.Activate

           CurrentWorkSheetLastRow = CurrentWorkSheet.Cells(CurrentWorkSheet.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

           PivotDataWorkSheetLastRow = PivotDataSheet.Cells(PivotDataSheet.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row + 1

           CurrentWorkSheet.Range(CurrentWorkSheet.Cells(25, "A"), Cells(CurrentWorkSheetLastRow, "L")).Copy _
                          Destination:=PivotDataSheet.Cells(PivotDataWorkSheetLastRow, "A")

      Next CurrentWorkSheetIndex

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jean-Pierre!

I made a few attempts, will make sure to include them next time so people can view the effort and try to help me develop my skills! thanks